# Is there anyway to taking user's location in a website

Tags: html, python-3.x, web

I want to make a website about sharing locations. But I couldn't find how to get user's location. This will be free application so I don't want to pay Google or anything else. I will use the python 3.x so there is no js.If it's free I will be very happy.

Comment: Are you using any framework like Django or is it raw python connected using flask ?

Answer (score 1):

Functionality such as geolocation requires the use of JavaScript. The feature you are looking for is the [Geolocation JavaScript API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API).

Python cannot do in the browser what JavaScript can do. They are used for completely different things in the context of websites. Python can be used on the backend, but to add most dynamic functionality on the frontend, you need JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to figure out a user's location, without directly asking them, is by their IP.
I found [python-geoip](https://pythonhosted.org/python-geoip/) through a quick Google search, which seems to offer what you're looking for.

Other than that, you could use HTML forms to actually ask the user their location, which doesn't require any JavaScript, just HTML, and then process that information on the backend.